# How do I write an output of one command into a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

Let's say we got a content of the following command in bash, which consists of several rows, and just one column:

```
tacmd listsystems | grep -i $i | awk '{print $1}'
```

This content is a list of offline machines you got on a server and you want to write it into the file e.g. `offline.lst`, in order to remove offline entries on a server from that file.

How do I write this specific content into `offline.lst`?

Answer (score 2):

```
tacmd listsystems | grep -i $i | awk '{print $1}' >> offline.lst
```

The `>>` operator tells bash to append output to a file.